# How to adjust data in DataFrame so they match the correct index dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

New programmer in need of help! 
I need to consolidate a data frame with hundreds of stock prices over many years. I have all the prices and dates in the same data frame, but they're scattered across the wrong rows since the first row is always the date it was purchased, and they're purchased at many different dates.

CURRENT DATA FRAME:

| DATE | A Dates | A Price | B Dates | B Price | XYZ Dates | XYZ Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/01 | 4/15/21 | 100 | 4/16/21 | 50 | 1/1/01 | 20 |
| 1/2/01 | 4/16/21 | 101 | 4/17/21 | 49 | 1/2/01 | 21 |
| 4/16/21 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 29 |
| 4/17/21 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 4/17/21 | 30 |

I want to manipulate the data frame so it drops all the columns with Stock A Dates, Stock B Dates, etc. and just has the prices all listed in the correct rows for the index date. So the new data frame would be:

END GOAL DATA FRAME:

| DATE | A Price | B Price | XYZ Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/01 | NaN | NaN | 20 |
| 1/1/02 | NaN | NaN | 21 |
| 4/16/21 | 101 | 50 | 29 |
| 4/17/21 | 101 | 49 | 30 |

Comment: Why is `4/15/21` not part of the date column? Also are the date and price columns for the same stocks always next to each other.

Comment: 4/15 will be. I was skipping rows since it will have every business day from 1/1/01 to 4/17/21. And yes, the dates and prices are always next to each other since it was uploaded from google finance. The start date is currently the first row for each stock regardless whether it was 20 years ago or yesterday.